# create tabbar slide effect / swiftUi

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created a tabbar, but I couldn't give the slide transition effect between pages.
I don't know how to do it. Can you.
I do not yet have the information to do.

```
 TabView{
            
            VStack{
                
                Text("1st screen").font(.largeTitle)
                
            }.tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                Text("1")
            }.tag(0)
            
            VStack{
                
                Text("2st screen").font(.largeTitle)
                
            }.tabItem{
                Image("img")
                Text("2")
            }.tag(1)
            VStack{
                
                Text("3st screen").font(.largeTitle)
                
            }.tabItem{
                Image("img")
                Text("3")
            }.tag(3)
            VStack{
                
                Text("4st screen").font(.largeTitle)
                
            }.tabItem{
                Image("img")
                Text("4")
            }.tag(4)
            
        }
```

Comment: By default there's none unless you use a `PageTabViewStyle`.

Comment: Do you have any examples of how I can do it? @pawello2222

Comment: If you need sliding *and* tabs at the bottom, then you need TabView with PageTabViewStyle (to slide) and custom tabbar at the bottom which programmatically switch tabs by click, ex. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62833840/12299030

Comment: The bottom bar disappears when I use what you've written. @Asperi