# create a slideshow with moving background

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I'm working on an app and I have created a spalsh screen as below:

Image 1

[image]

So Image 1 is the look and feel I want but I would like to add an automatic carrousel to display the text as shown in Animation 1 below:

Animation 1:

[image]

For Image 1, I have done the code below:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
           // Text("Hello, World!")
            Spacer().frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: 
RegisterLoginView(isLoginScreen: true)) {
                    Spacer(minLength: 100)
                    MyButtonView(stringOfButton: login,
                        isInverse: true,
                        btnHeight: 40)
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                    Spacer(minLength: 100)

                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: 
 RegisterLoginView(isLoginScreen: false)) {
                    Spacer(minLength: 100)
                    MyButtonView(stringOfButton: register,
                        isInverse: false,
                        btnHeight: 40)
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                    Spacer(minLength: 100)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
    .background(Image("guestBackground")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
}
```

As you see on the original image below, Image 1 only show the middle. So I would like to have Image 1 upgraded to :

- text in the middle of each view of animation 1 showing on Image1 and automatically sliding from one to the other. Only 3 slides.
- image right side for slide 1, middle of image on slide 2 and right side of image on slide 3. like when the text is displayed it looks like in background you are looking inside the appartment.

[image]

So it's look like you are moving in the image from left to right

Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62833840/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi not really because it's doing already what I am doing. I am looking for an automatic move and also a background image of each slide which 1/3 of an asset. slide one is left side of the image, slide 2 middle and slide 3 right.

Answer (score 0):

try the following approach for the carousel.
It uses the tag() for the TabView and a Timer to automatically change them
going from slide 1 to 3 and 3 to 1.
As for the background image ...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var slide = 1
    @State var forward = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TabView(selection: $slide) {
                    Text("--1--").tag(1)  
                    Text("--2--").tag(2)
                    Text("--3--").tag(3)
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: true) { timer in
                if forward {
                    slide += 1
                    if slide == 3 { forward = false }
                } else {
                    slide -= 1
                    if slide == 1 { forward = true }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```