# Move Index View above home indicator in Tab View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have reached an annoying issue with SwiftUI. I have a horizontal pager with vertical scroll views as pages. It is defined as simple as they come,

```
TabView(selection: $selected) {
    ForEach(focus!.list.things) { thing in
        FullView(thing: thing).tag(thing)
    }
}
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
.indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
```

and

```
struct FullView: View {
    let thing: Thing
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This produces a view which does what I want, except it does not reach all the way down below the home indicator.

[image]

I can solve this by adding `.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)` to the `TabView`, but that produces another displeasing result where the page indicator collides with the home indicator.

[image]

---

**Is there any reasonable way accomplish full height vertical scroll while keeping the index page indicator above the home indicator?**

Code to recreate issue:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isSheetUp = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Present") {
            isSheetUp.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetUp) {
            Sheet()
        }
    }
    
    struct Sheet: View {
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                TabView() {
                    Page()
                    Page()
                    Page()
                }
                // Comment this to switch layout issue
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
                .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
                .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
                .navigationTitle("Title")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct Page: View {
        var body: some View {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.teal)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(minHeight: 10000)
                }
            }.background(Color.brown)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add `ignoresSafeArea` to your `FullView`.

Comment: @Asperi Scroll view still cropped off on safe area, like in picture 1 :(

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example for testing/debugging so we do you reinvent your code.

Comment: @Asperi i got u, made a reproducible sample now

Comment: According to analysis of view hierarchy internal `UIPageControl` has no constrains but layout strictly by frame that is why it does not react on any safe area configurations but moved with parent bottom edge. It is hardly possible that Apple will change this in near future, so I recommend to consider implementing custom page control and hide default one. Swipe will work and for how to switch pages programmatically from custom control you can review https://stackoverflow.com/a/62833840/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks, will try to do some introspect magic n add a safe area offset. If anyone knows how to do this please answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: See also [@nekno's fantastic additions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71262058/3398839)!

---

This is possible if you create a custom `UIPageControl`, manually tag each tab in the `TabView`, and make sure to keep track of the `numberOfPages`:

```swift
struct PageControlView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var currentPage: Int
    @Binding var numberOfPages: Int

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIPageControl {
        let uiView = UIPageControl()
        uiView.backgroundStyle = .prominent
        uiView.currentPage = currentPage
        uiView.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
        return uiView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIPageControl, context: Context) {
        uiView.currentPage = currentPage
        uiView.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isSheetUp = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Present") {
            isSheetUp.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetUp) {
            Sheet()
        }
    }

    struct Sheet: View {
        @State var currentPage = 0
        @State var numberOfPages = 3

        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                ZStack {
                    TabView(selection: $currentPage) {
                        Page().tag(0)
                        Page().tag(1)
                        Page().tag(2)
                    }
                    // Comment this to switch layout issue
                    .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
                    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                    .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
                    .navigationTitle("Title")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        PageControlView(currentPage: $currentPage, numberOfPages: $numberOfPages)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct Page: View {
        var body: some View {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.teal)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(minHeight: 10000)
                }
            }.background(Color.brown)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@Coder-256's answer set me on the right path, and I added a couple enhancements you might find useful.

1. The `UIPageControl` normally iterates through the pages when you tap on it. As written, the indicator in the page control was changing, but the pages weren't actually changing, so I added a target for the page control's `.valueChanged` event.

   When setting the current page based on the new changed value, wrapping the assignment in a `withAnimation` closure ensure the page animates to the next page, otherwise it just replaces the current page instantaneously.
2. `TabView` will work with any valid `tag` values, which just need to conform to `Hashable`.

   To work with the page control, you need those tag values to be convertible to `Int` values, but it's common practice to use a strongly-typed, named value for tags, so I added support for an `enum` that conforms to `RawRepresentable` with a backing type of `Int`.

   Others may find it easier to just use hard-coded integers for the tag values, so if you ever reordered the pages in your `TabView` you wouldn't have to remember to reorder the cases in your `enum`, but to each their own.
3. The `UIPageControl` and its parent `ViewHost` that hosts the `UIViewRepresentable` instance both have auto resizing masks that result in their frames expanding to consume the horizontal space of the containing superview.

   Both the page control and the view host participate in hit testing, so they intercept touches to the left and right of the page control when you actually intend to scroll the content underneath.

   Adding the `allowsHitTesting(false)` view modifier eliminates that behavior, but also disables all interaction with the page control, so it breaks the tap/paging functionality.

   I played around with various solutions, and the easiest seems to be to just set a frame on the page control that requests a `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` of `0`, and as a result the view shrinks to its intrinsic content size.

```swift
struct PageControlView<T: RawRepresentable>: UIViewRepresentable where T.RawValue == Int {
    @Binding var currentPage: T
    @Binding var numberOfPages: Int
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIPageControl {
        let uiView = UIPageControl()
        uiView.backgroundStyle = .prominent
        uiView.currentPage = currentPage.rawValue
        uiView.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
        uiView.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.valueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
        return uiView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIPageControl, context: Context) {
        uiView.currentPage = currentPage.rawValue
        uiView.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
    }
}

extension PageControlView {
    final class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: PageControlView
        
        init(_ parent: PageControlView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        @objc func valueChanged(sender: UIPageControl) {
            guard let currentPage = T(rawValue: sender.currentPage) else {
                return
            }

            withAnimation {
                parent.currentPage = currentPage
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentPage: Pages = .myFirstPage
    @State private var numberOfPages = Pages.allCases.count
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            TabView(selection: $currentPage) {
                MyFirstPage()
                    .tag(Pages.myFirstPage)
                
                MySecondPage()
                    .tag(Pages.mySecondPage)
                
                MyThirdPage()
                    .tag(Pages.myThirdPage)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            
            UIPageControlView(currentPage: $currentPage, numberOfPages: $numberOfPages)
                .frame(maxWidth: 0, maxHeight: 0)
                .padding(22) // 22 seems to mimic SwiftUI's `PageIndexView` placement from the bottom edge
        }
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    enum Pages: Int, CaseIterable {
        case myFirstPage
        case mySecondPage
        case myThirdPage
    }
}
```