# SwiftUI: customizing TabView's PageTabViewStyle to show tags instead of dots

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using the following code to show a list of pages horizontally using `TabView`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyHStack {
                PageView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(0..<30) { i in
                ZStack {
                    Color.black
                    Text("Row: \(i)").foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            .padding(.all, 10)
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200)
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
}
```

however, this shows dots at the bottom:

[image]

what I want to achieve is:

1. hiding the dots.
2. adding `Text` views (or tags) on top of `PageView` to show the rows that belongs to a specific category, exactly like what's done in YouTube app:

[image]

is this possible with `PageTabViewStyle` ?

Comment: Just use style `PageIndexViewStyle.never` and change tabs programmatically on tags selection as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62833840/12299030.

Comment: Cool, post it as answer to close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use style `PageIndexViewStyle.never` and change tabs programmatically on tags selection as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62833840/12299030.