# How to switch to another TabView in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I know this question has been asked before and I found a few of them but mine is slightly different.

I found this for example:

[Programmatically change to another tab in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62504400/programmatically-change-to-another-tab-in-swiftui)

which works fine if you have the `struct ContentView: View {...}` and `struct FirstView: View {...}` on the same Swift file.

But in my project, I have the `struct ContentView: View {...}` in 1 Swift file and `struct FirstView: View {...}` in another separate swift file.

for that reason, when I use `@Binding var tabSelection: Int` in my `FirstView()` file, I get this error in my ContentView file: `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments`

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Comment: It would not make any deference in result at all, you probably running in another issue! could you show your real used code?

Comment: @swiftPunk, its a large code. let me see if I can minify it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example, if you try this example it would working! It would not make any deference in result at all if you put them in deferent files!

### File ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var tabSelection = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
            
            FirstView(tabSelection: $tabSelection)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Tab 1")
                }
                .tag(1)
            
            SecondView(tabSelection: $tabSelection)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Tab 2")
                }
                .tag(2)
        }
    }
}
```

### File FirstView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    
    @Binding var tabSelection: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: { tabSelection = 2 }) { Text("Change to tab 2") }
        
    }
}
```

### File SecondView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SecondView: View {
    
    @Binding var tabSelection: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: { tabSelection = 1 }) { Text("Change to tab 1") }
        
    }
}
```