# SwiftUI Change TabView with a Button

Tags: swiftui, tabview

I have a tabview that I would like to change to another tab when a button is pressed. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Use the tan view with “selection”

Comment: duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62504400/programmatically-change-to-another-tab-in-swiftui

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but this is how I got my tabs in a TabView to act more like buttons and toggle a number instead of directly calling a view (totally understand that this is a weird way to do it, but given what I already had this ended up being easier).

- I have two black rectangles that each take up 1/2 of the screen which switch dependent on the views. If you don't want these, you can set the fill color to white or add text instead, etc. This would also allow you to get rid of GeometryReader.
- Can use @State or @Binding var to track the tab showing (in this case, viewId)
- Modify viewId when changing tabs
- Pass viewId as a binding into the TabView so it's automatically tracked
- Tell SwiftUI which tab it should show dependent on the viewId

So here's the code! (Pretty messy since I'm still working on it, but hope you get the idea)

```
struct Tabs: View{
    @Binding var viewId: Int

    var body: some View{
        GeometryReader { geo in
            TabView(selection: $viewId) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(viewId != 7 ? Color.black : Color.white)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width/2, height: 6)
                    .padding(.trailing, geo.size.width/2)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        viewId = 1
                    }
                    .tabItem{
                        Label("Submission", systemImage: "star")
                    }
                    .tag(1)
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(viewId == 7 ? Color.black : Color.white)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width/2, height: 6)
                    .padding(.leading, geo.size.width/2)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        viewId = 7
                    }
                    .tabItem{
                        Label("Past Submissions", systemImage: "star")
                    }
                    .tag(7)
            }
            .frame(height:100)
        }
    }
}
```

Then in any other view, (I used ContentView), can display this with this line:

```
Tabs(viewId = $viewId)
```

Given that I have this in my ContentView (or desired view)

```
@State private var viewId = 1
```